# jQuery(this) in each only get the last value

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scope, each

I have this piece of code and the variable *toto* has the same value in each cells of the array (the other threads say that a scope problem but I use **`var titi=jQuery(this).text();`** and `titi=jQuery(this).text();`

## HTML

```
<table name='xnnjz'><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></table>
```

## JavaScript

```
var i=0;
jQuery("table['name=xnnjz'] tr.child-of-application"+indep+" td").each(function () {
    var titi=jQuery(this).text();
    toto[i]=titi;
    i=i+1;
});
console.log(toto);
```

In console log :

```
toto=[3,3,3]
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the array out side each to access it out side each, Also modify your selector as I could not see any class `child-of-application`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qVeRg/1/)**

```
var i = 0;
var toto = [];
jQuery("table[name=xnnjz] td").each(function() {
    var titi = jQuery(this).text();
    toto[i] = titi;
    i = i + 1;
});
```

Simplified version of above

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qVeRg/2/)**

```
var toto = [];
jQuery("table[name=xnnjz] td").each(function(idx, item) {    
    toto[idx] = $(item).text();  
});
```

You can also use jQuery map()

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qVeRg/)**

```
var toto = jQuery("table[name=xnnjz] td").map(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text();    
});
```

Comment: @Adil would you mind taking a look at my jquery loop i'm having a problem with iterating and my variable being overwritten http://stackoverflow.com/q/18929265/804087

Answer (score 0):

See your issues is here:

```
jQuery("table['name=xnnjz'] tr.child-of-application"+indep+" td").each(function
 //-----------^----------^---Either remove it or do it like this below

jQuery("table[name='xnnjz'] td").each(function
```